# object data null after get request in Dotnet webapi project

Tags: c#, .net-core, microservices, webapi, data-layers

I have created two model classes Organisation.cs and Employee.cs

```
public class Organisation
    {
        private static string organisationName="FALCON";
        private int employeeCount=2;
        private string ceoName;
        private List<string> departmentNames;
        [JsonIgnore]
        private List<Employee> employees;
        private List<Address> addesses;
        private bool isCeoChangeAvailable= true;
        public string OrganisationName 
        {
            get {return organisationName;} 
            set {organisationName = value;} 
        }
        public int EmployeeCount
        {
            get {return employeeCount;}
            set { employeeCount = value; }
        }
        public string CeoName 
        {
            get { return ceoName; }
            set { ceoName = value; } 
        }
        public List<string> Departments 
        { 
            get { return departmentNames; } 
            set { departmentNames = value; } 
        }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public List<Employee> Employees 
        {
            get {return employees; }
            set {employees=value; } 
        }
        public List<Address> OfficeAdresses 
        { 
            get {return addesses; } 
            set { addesses = value; } 
        }
        public bool IsCeoChange 
        { 
            get{ return isCeoChangeAvailable; }
            set { isCeoChangeAvailable = value; } 
        }
        public Organisation(string ceoName,List<string> departments,List<Address> addresses)
        {
            this.CeoName = ceoName;
            this.Departments = departments;
            this.OfficeAdresses = addresses;

        }
        public Organisation() { }
    }
```

and an employee class

```
public class Employee
    {
        private Guid employeeId;
        private string name;
        private string departmentName;
        private bool isManager;
        private int salary;

        public Guid Id
        {
            get
            { return employeeId;}
            set
            { employeeId = value;}
        }
        public string Name 
        { 
            get 
            { return name;} 
            set 
            { name = value;} 
        }

        public bool IsManager 
        {
            get 
            { return isManager;} 
            set 
            { isManager = value;} 
        }
        public string DepartmentName 
        {
            get { return departmentName;}
            set { departmentName = value;} 
        }
        public int Salary 
        { 
            get { return salary; } 
            set { salary = value; } }
        public Employee()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

have a two controllers for Employee and Organisation, I am trying to post Organisation data and storing it in a variable.

In my organisaiton controller I have this method

```
public IActionResult PostOrganisationData(Organisation organisation) 
        {
            _organisationData.PostOrganisationDetails(organisation);
            return Created(HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Request.Host + HttpContext.Request.Path + "/" + organisation.OrganisationName, organisation);
        }
```

In my datalayer have a class MockEmployeeData which implements IOrganisationData interface
here is the code where I am constructing the Organisation object and assigning it to an instance of Organisation object. During the request The organisation object holds the assigned data. Here is the code

```
private Organisation organisation = new Organisation();
public Organisation PostOrganisationDetails(Organisation organisation)
        {
            Organisation organisationObject = new Organisation(organisation.CeoName, organisation.Departments, organisation.OfficeAdresses);
            organisation = organisationObject;
            return organisation;
        }
```

When I call the Get action method which gets the organisation details from the controller the previously assigned object has properties with null. Here is the get method

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public IActionResult GetOrganisationDetails()
{
    var organisationData=_organisationData.GetOrganisationData();
    return Ok(organisationData);
}

 public Organisation GetOrganisationData()
 {
      Organisation organisationObject = new Organisation();
      organisationObject = organisation;
      return organisationObject;
 }
```

Here in this method I,m assigning the variable which holds the previously assigned data from post request and getting back the object where all properties have gone null now.Please help me solve this

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting no values in your `PostOrganisationData` post method?

Comment: No for property `List<Employees>` in `organisation.cs` class are being set to null

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your properties in your `Organisation` model class to nullable. Now you can do this by either manually making each property nullable in your class:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public string? OrganisationName 
    {
        get {return organisationName;} 
        set {organisationName = value;} 
    }
    public int? EmployeeCount
    {
        get {return employeeCount;}
        set { employeeCount = value; }
    }
    public string? CeoName 
    {
        get { return ceoName; }
        set { ceoName = value; } 
    }
    public List<string?> Departments 
    { 
        get { return departmentNames; } 
        set { departmentNames = value; } 
    }

    ....so on
```

Or you can globally enable this property by editing your `csproj` file which contains your project properties:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
   <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
   <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```